# How to redirect to some link in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to redirect to url in jquery but it redirects on same page like
when i try to redirect to this url- `any.com`
it redirects to
[www.page.com/any.com](http://www.page.com/any.com)

```
          setTimeout(function(){
               window.open(redirect_url);
              },2000);
```

any thoughts ?

Comment: use this to for a new window redirect => `window.open(redirect_url, '_blank');`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `window.location.href` to redirect as

```
var redirect_url = "http://any.com";
setTimeout(function(){
     window.location.href = redirect_url;
},2000);
```

If your `redirect_url` doesn't have `http/https` protocol you should add it to redirect url as http://any.com instead of only any.com

Comment: Instead of answering duplicates question - mark them as duplicate - its take less effort to do that instead of a new answer.

Comment: Not working sir

Comment: It redirects me to  http://site/google.com

Comment: If it's not redirecting correctly, but *is* redirecting, then state that.  Saying "not working" is completely useless.  If it's going tot he wrong url, then you're passing the wrong url.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try with your code, you missed only to add http:// before your url.

```
let redirect_url = 'http://www.page.com/any.com'
setTimeout(function(){
               window.open(redirect_url);
              },2000);
```